# Unity - Set player position after loading scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, load, scene

I am Trying to set player position after loading a scene. The program runs ok sometimes, but sometimes it places the player in the wrong position.

This is a video showing this strange behaviour: https://youtu.be/MFl9P3taV0Y

This is the code:

```cs
public class IniciaHeroi : MonoBehaviour
{
  public GameObject GM;
  private int startPosition;

  void Awake()
  {
    startPosition = GM.GetComponent<StartScene>().startPosition;
    if(startPosition == 1)
    {
      transform.position = new Vector3(119,4.67f,36);
      transform.GetComponent<HeroiMovimento>().rot = -30;
      Debug.Log("StartPosition1: " + transform.position);
    }

    if(startPosition == 2)
    {
      transform.position = new Vector3(49,13.8f,167);
      transform.GetComponent<HeroiMovimento>().rot = 100;
      Debug.Log("StartPosition2: " + transform.position);
    } 
  }
}
```

Debug log shows always the correct position but, as you can see in the video, something changes the position.

Can anyone point the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the Character controller attached to my player. For some strange reason Character Controller do not change its own transform.position when i change player transform.position.

So the solution is to disable Character Controller before change player position and Enable it after the change.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!! Having the same issue, and took me so long to find this. Finally I was able to solve by using disabling the Controller and then enabling it:

example:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>().enabled = false;
gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(-31, 1, -10);
gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>().enabled = true;
```